# How to retrieve count from date ranges that overlap?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the count of records that are within a x day interval. The intervals are overlapping though. Example: For a given time frame (lets say 30 days) I want to get the count for the first 5 days ( day 1  - day 5 inclusive), then count for day 2 - day 6, then day 3 - day 7, then day 4 - day 8, etc etc until I reach day 26 - day 30.

Whats the best way to go about this?
Is it possible to retrieve all the data for 30 days then group by?
Get queries for each sub interval then union them together?
Another method?
What would the query look like?
Example output, range is not necessarily but helpful.

```
count, range
   30, 2016-01-01 - 2016-01-05
   32, 2016-01-02 - 2016-01-06
   34, 2016-01-03 - 2016-01-07
   33, 2016-01-04 - 2016-01-08
```

Hopefully its understandable, if not please let me know and i'll clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: I would generate a table of the ranges and then join the original table to it when dates are BETWEEN the upper and lower ranges group by and count.  I haven't added code because I don't know the best way to generate the table in mysql but you could look around and find that answer I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join with a table that contains each date range. You can create this on the fly with a bunch of `UNION`s.

```
SELECT t1.start, t1.end, COUNT(t2.date) AS count
FROM (SELECT '2016-01-01' AS start, '2016-01-05' AS end
      UNION
      SELECT '2016-01-02', '2016-01-06'
      UNION
      SELECT '2016-01-03', '2016-01-07'
      UNION
      SELECT '2016-01-04', '2016-01-08'
      ...) AS t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS t2 ON t2.date BETWEEN t1.start AND t1.end
GROUP BY t1.start
```

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures that you see the 0 counts for any date ranges with no records.

Comment: This is what I was leaning on. Good catch on the LEFT JOIN too! Would have missed it.